# How to substitute part of a script with specific url elements?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

As a test I've tried to extract the part of the url I need and display it in a random div on my page and it works fine. Here is the function I use:

```
add_action('init','add_get_val');
function add_get_val() { 
global $wp; 
$wp->add_query_var('category'); 
}
```

and I added this to the body of my page:

```
            <?php
        // Test if the query exists at the URL
if ( get_query_var('category') ) {

// If so echo the value
echo get_query_var('category');
}
        ?>
```

When I try using this same code within my embed to change the value of 'category' to whatever has been extracted from my url, nothing happens. Here is the original embed:

```
<script src="https://serviceexample.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=idexample&amp;category=default"></script>
```

I changed it to:

```
<script src="https://serviceexample.com/embed/embed/ot-embed.js?embedId=idexample&amp;category="<?php
if ( get_query_var('category') ) {

echo get_query_var('category');
}
        ?>""></script>
```

Any Ideas?

Comment: `if($_GET['category']=='category1'){echo ...}` etc

Comment: Thanks for the help. I've figure out part of the problem and edited my post